# Display object into spark list?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex-mobile

How can I display a generic object into spark list? I'm trying make a chat, like whatsapp, where the user can send a emoticon, images and videos.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use custom ItemRenderer.

Useful links:

- [About Spark List](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff923c946c5112135c8ee9e-7fff.html)
- [Custom itemRenderer 1](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html)
- [Custom itemRenderer 2](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html)
- [ItemRenderer for mobile](https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/6/24/Building-a-Mobile-ItemRenderer-in-Flex)

Comment: Ok Crabar, thanks for your answer. But what i want is that my list or my repeater or something else to display chat list with images, videos and text. Like 'whatsapp'. I have no idea to do this. Can you help me

Comment: You can implement your custom item renderer with any components what you want. In situation when you need to display different items in one list you can choose one of two ways: create huge item renderer that display different content depending on the current data, or create a few item renderers for List and choose appropriate item renderer depending on the data (with using itemRendererFunction). Look in Flex docs next properties of Spark List: itemRenderer, itemRendererFunction.

Comment: Perfect Crabar. The knowledge, push you for way so long. You save my day, and renew my hope ;)